# Invalid custom Spring Security Authentication with MockMvc - Spring/MockMvc Bug?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-security, mockmvc

I have a Spring Boot app, based on Spring Boot version 2.7.7.
And I'm experiencing some behaviour that I cannot explain.
**It seems that an annotation on a Controller parameter causes the injected custom Authentication object to be broken**, but maybe I just got something wrong?

I have a custom Authentication class that I use to augment my JWT based authentication:

```
public interface CustomAuthenticationToken extends Authentication {
    Optional<String> getCustomClaim();
}
```

For tests, I have this mock implementation:

```
public class MockCustomAuthenticationToken implements CustomAuthenticationToken {
  // implement all the methods with dummy values
}
```

I also have this annotation to be used on test methods:

```
@WithSecurityContext(factory = WithCustomAuthenticationTokenContextFactory.class)
public @interface WithCustomAuthenticationToken {
  String customClaim() default "mockvalue";
}
```

And this factory class:

```
public class WithCustomAuthenticationTokenContextFactory implements WithSecurityContextFactory<WithCustomAuthenticationToken> {
    @Override
    public SecurityContext createSecurityContext(WithCustomAuthenticationToken withCustomAuthenticationToken) {
        SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext();

        List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = //...
        Authentication auth = new MockCustomAuthenticationToken(
                withCustomAuthenticationToken.customClaim(),
                grantedAuthorities
        );

        context.setAuthentication(auth);
        return context;
    }
}
```

My test case looks like this:

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class SpringBootTest {

    @Autowired
    protected WebApplicationContext context;

    protected MockMvc mockMvc;

    @BeforeEach
    protected void beforeEach() {
       mockMvc = webAppContextSetup(context)
            .apply(springSecurity())
            .build();
    }

    @Test
    @WithCustomAuthenticationToken(customClaim = "claim")
    public void test1() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(
                    MockMvcRequestBuilders.get(
                            "/testcontroller"
                    )
            )
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

This is my controller that I can use to reproduce this issue:
I'm requesting the Spring Authentication information in the controller, 4 times, in a different way:

```
@RestController
public class DownloadCounterRestServiceV1 {
    @GetMapping("/testcontroller")
    public void testcontroller(
        // As CustomAuthenticationToken object
        CustomAuthenticationToken customAuthenticationToken1,

        // The same as 1, but with an added Springfox annotation!
        @ApiIgnore
        CustomAuthenticationToken customAuthenticationToken2,

        // As generic Authentication object
        Authentication authentication1,

        // The same as 3 but with the added annotation
        @ApiIgnore
        Authentication authentication2
    ) {
        log.info("customAuthenticationToken1: {}", customAuthenticationToken1);
        log.info("customAuthenticationToken2: {}", customAuthenticationToken2);
        log.info("authentication1: {}", authentication1);
        log.info("authentication2: {}", authentication2);
    }
}
```

The log output is

```
customAuthenticationToken1: MockCustomAuthenticationToken(customClaim="...")
customAuthenticationToken2: {}
authentication1: MockCustomAuthenticationToken(customClaim="...")
authentication2: MockCustomAuthenticationToken(customClaim="...")
```

So for any reason, **if I use a custom interface AND an annotation before that parameter, Spring will not set the correct MockCustomAuthenticationToken** but instead an empty object of type `jdk.proxy2.$Proxy123`

The same effect happens when I use `@Autowired` instead of `@ApiIgnore`, so it does not seem to be caused by the annotation itself.

Is there anything I missed? Where does this behaviour come from?

Comment: If you are using Spring Boot and have `mockMvc = webAppContextSetup(context)` in your test you are doing it wrong. `@Autowired` inside a request handling method doesn't do anything, the `@ApiIgnore` isn't a spring annotation but for swagger/openapi (I assume) and doesn't do anything either. I'm not that familier with Spring Fox but it could be that there is some argument resolver for that specific annotation. Anyway please show your full test class instead of snippets.

Comment: I added the full test class.
What do you mean by "you are doing it wrong?" Is there a better way to set up this test?

I am aware that neither of the annoatations should change anything for the test, that is why I'm really confused that they break the test.

Comment: You already have `@AutoConfigureMockMvc` hence you should autowire `MockMvc` and remove your `@BeforeEach` annotated method. Spring Boot will setup MockMvc with the setup as you have configured, no need to do anything for that yourself.